# ASP.NET MVC Razor: How to render a Razor Partial View's HTML inside the controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to generate a HTML of a given partial view on ASP.NET view engine [is known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286132/asp-net-mvc-getting-a-partial-views-html-from-inside-of-the-controller).

But if this functionality is used on razor partial view it does not work, as exception says the partial view does not derive from "UserControl".

How to fix the rendering to support razor partial view?

I need this because I generate emails form this partial views ...

**UPDATE:**

Code that fails (@mcl):

```
public string RenderPartialToString(string controlName, object viewData)
    {
        ViewPage viewPage = new ViewPage() { ViewContext = new ViewContext() };
        viewPage.Url = this.GetUrlHelper();

        string fullControlName = "~/Views/Email/" + controlName + ".ascx";

        viewPage.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(viewData);
        viewPage.Controls.Add(viewPage.LoadControl(fullControlName));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                viewPage.RenderControl(tw);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far that generates the exception?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

```
@Html.Partial("nameOfPartial", Model)
```

**Update**

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    ViewData.Model = model;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is how you render a partial view inside a view. But how to render it inside a controller action?

Comment: Great this is it now! Works with Razon and ASP notation.

Comment: One subquestiuon: How to render the view that is in another Controller scope then the current? Lets say it is in "EmailController" scope (Email view folder)?

Comment: Create a new ControllerContext

Comment: @jgauffin: For some reason, I don't have `Partial` on `@Html`. What am I missing?

Comment: This was a great solution.  I had the exact need with email and opted to use this.

Comment: @PeterStegnar See my answer, it is built in a way that allows you to throw the method in a Util class.

Comment: I am trying to understand why you would ever want or need to do this

Comment: @MarkHomer: Five years ago (when this answer were written) it wasnt as easy to use Razor standalone. This could for instance be used to render emails as other comments have suggested.

Comment: @jgauffin This code does not execute the jquery code in the view before giving the output. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: @AmeyKhadatkar: no. jquery is client side, the view is generated at server side before being sent to the browser.

Answer (score 7):

Although adequate answers have already been given, I'd like to propose a less verbose solution, that can be used without the helper methods available in an MVC controller class.  Using a third party library called "RazorEngine" you can use .Net file IO to get the contents of the razor file and call

```
string html = Razor.Parse(razorViewContentString, modelObject);
```

Get the third party library [here](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the `RenderView Controller extension` from [here](http://awesome.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Misc&referringTitle=Home)
([source](http://awesome.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AwesomeMvc/ControllerExtensions.cs))

and use it like this:

```
public ActionResult Do() {
var html = this.RenderView("index", theModel);
...
}
```

it works for **razor** and **web-forms** viewengines

Comment: Checked the link. @ChurkNorris is the author of [ASP.net MVC Awesome](http://www.aspnetawesome.com/), which is a commercial product [from version 2.0](http://awesome.codeplex.com/releases/) (currently latest release Mar 12 2012). [Version 1.9](http://awesome.codeplex.com/releases/view/66067) (latest release Jun 9 2011) is still open source, but probably won't be developed any more. Any forks of 1.9 out there?

Comment: @Omu: RenderView is void. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.renderview(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @Roland this is a custom controller extension

Answer (score 1):

I saw that someone was wondering how to do it for another controller.

In my case I had all of my email templates in the Views/Email folder, but you could modify this to pass in the controller in which you have views associated for.

```
public static string RenderViewToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        var oldController = controller.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

        if (controller.GetType() != typeof(EmailController))
            controller.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Email";

        var oldModel = controller.ViewData.Model;
        controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        try
        {
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName,
                                                                           null);

                var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

                //Cleanup
                controller.ViewData.Model = oldModel;
                controller.RouteData.Values["controller"] = oldController;

                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Essentially what this does is take a controller, such as AccountController and modify it to think it's an EmailController so that the code will look in the `Views/Email` folder. It's necessary to do this because the `FindView` method doesn't take a straight up path as a parameter, it wants a `ControllerContext`.

Once done rendering the string, it returns the AccountController back to its initial state to be used by the Response object.

Answer (score 1):

great code; little hint: if you sometimes have to bypass more data and not only the viewmodel ..

```
 if (model is ViewDataDictionary)
 {
     controller.ViewData = model as ViewDataDictionary;
 } else {
     controller.ViewData.Model = model;
 }
```

Comment: You have not completed your answer

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing @jgauffin answer as an HtmlHelper extension:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString RenderPartialViewToString(
        this HtmlHelper html, 
        ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        ViewDataDictionary viewData,
        TempDataDictionary tempData,
        string viewName, 
        object model)
    {
        viewData.Model = model;
        string result = String.Empty;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, viewResult.View, viewData, tempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            result = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(result);
    }
}
```

Usage in a razor view:

```
Html.RenderPartialViewToString(ViewContext, ViewData, TempData, "Search", Model)
```

Comment: Could you explain the difference with using @Html.Partial(string partialViewName, object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)? What are the benefits since it requires HtmlHelper?