# Getting view as string in asp.net mvc for email sending

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, email, view, razor

I want to use [Mailgun](https://mailgun.net/) (or maybe [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/)) to send emails from my app.

This is pretty straightforward cause I can use [RestSharp](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/RestSharp) to interact with their api.

The problem lies in the fact that generating an HTML email is a PITA if I cant use razor.
I know there are two nuget packages ([Postal](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/postal), [MvcMailer](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MvcMailer)) that handle this problem quite nicely but they force me to use a SMTP server and I dont want or need that at all.

I just want to keep using the Mailgun API to send emails but I want to have a way to generate the markup for those emails using Razor.

How can I do this?

Please Help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Razor: How to render a Razor Partial View's HTML inside the controller action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344533/asp-net-mvc-razor-how-to-render-a-razor-partial-views-html-inside-the-controlle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a partial you can render it to a string, as in the following SO question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344533/asp-net-mvc-razor-how-to-render-a-razor-partial-views-html-inside-the-controlle)