# ASP.Net MVC render view from another controller to string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am struggling for hours to render a view from another controller to a string. 
I use that to generate email templates. For this I created a controller called EmailController that has a view ConfirmationEmail.cshtml 
I want to render that view in Home.Index action for example. The reason for this is organisation because I want to have the email views in ~/View/Email/... and EmailController will be used just for rendering them. Also ~/View/Shared/Email/... will be ok if you have another suggestion.

Do you suggest another approach?

I saw this thread [ASP.NET MVC Razor: How to render a Razor Partial View's HTML inside the controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344533/asp-net-mvc-razor-how-to-render-a-razor-partial-views-html-inside-the-controll) but I cannot make it work.

I need something like:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
        {
                EmailController emailController = new EmailController();
                ControllerContext context = new ControllerContext(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext, emailController);
                EmailController.RenderPartialViewToString(emailController, "ConfirmationEmail", new EmailModel());
}
```

This does not work :( and the viewResult  object in RenderPartialViewToString method is null.
Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: My I please ask why doing it in other controller?

Comment: I want this like an email generation utility ... and I will call it from another controller ... for example after a user register I will generate confirmation email and send it. Not all necessarily in Account.Register action. I added EmailController for better views organisation. Practically ConfirmationEmail is a shared view ... but I don't want it in the Shared folder.

Comment: You are using .cshtml files to render an e-mail, because Razor makes it convenient. But now you have a problem with MVC execution pipeline, and resolving it (if ever possible) will be ugly. I'd suggest rendering e-mails in a separate helper method, and calling it both from your EmailController and from your other controllers

Comment: Your context variable isn't being used above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check out MvcMailer project?

https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Wonderful library.

Comment: @RaduD glad to help, I use it in my own application and it's really great, plus it's open source so if something goes wrong you have a chance to fix it and contribute it back :D

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [FluentEmail](http://lukencode.com/2010/04/11/fluent-email-in-net/)?  It takes a few seconds to setup using Nuget, and you get all the goodness of Razor templates, with a simple to use email tool.

Answer (score 0):

`EmailController.RenderPartialViewToString` you passed in `emailController` instead of `context`

Modify that line to something like:

```
  EmailController.RenderPartialViewToString(context, "ConfirmationEmail", new EmailModel())
```

Comment: that does not work ... because the internals use Request.Data in order to find correct View