# How to convert PartialViewResult to MvcHtmlString in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How to convert PartialViewResult to MvcHtmlString in MVC3?

I want to change the HTML string and replace some ID's index in resulted  PartialViewResult  from some Partial view.

```
 e.g.
 <input type="hidden" value="1" name="[0].lstMatches[4].match_rule_id"> 
 to
 <input type="hidden" value="1" name="[0].lstMatches[6].match_rule_id">
```

Model Like

> return PartialView("_MatchPartial", objRETURN).**TOMvcHTMLSTRING()**;

looking for this TOMvcHTMLSTRING() type of function.

can anybody help me in that?

Thanks in Advance,
Amit Prajapati

Comment: Why do you need this? It's not clear what the original issue is. What exactly do you want to change and why? Please provide more details.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I have used IList on Partialview.
How by the @Ajax.actionlink, I am dynamically adding partialview to div and this Div contains controls with the <input type="hidden" value="1" name="[0].lstMatches[5].match_rule_id">
, when I do Ajax post on this Div, I am not getting this dynamically added extra record but getting already exist record, e.g. name= [0].lstMatches[6].match_rule_id, 
My model do not contains new records, So, I guess I need to generate HTML with the proper indexed. does it? or any other ways?

Comment: Please post your complete code with what you have tried so far?

Comment: It's very long Main view & a PartialView, not feasible to post here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Razor: How to render a Razor Partial View's HTML inside the controller action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344533/asp-net-mvc-razor-how-to-render-a-razor-partial-views-html-inside-the-controll)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected string RenderView(PartialViewResult result)
{
  using (var sw = new StringWriter())
  {
    result.View = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, result.ViewName).View;
    ViewContext vc = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, result.View, result.ViewData, result.TempData, sw);
    result.View.Render(vc, sw);
    return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
  }
}
```