# dynamically changing @section in asp.net view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on asp.net MVC 3 application and I have a layout page with a section like this:

```
   <div class="rt-block">
                                <div id="rt-mainbody">
                                    @if (IsSectionDefined("BodyTitle"))
                                    {
                                        <div class="rt-headline">
                                            <h1 class="rt-article-title">
                                                @RenderSection("BodyTitle", false)
                                            </h1>
                                        </div>   
                                    }
                                    <div class="clear">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        @RenderBody()
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

In My View, I am defining the section like this:

```
@section BodyTitle {
    <span>Verify</span> Your Identity
}

partail view here
```

This View loads one of two partial views depending on link click.

I want that when one partial view is loaded then section has different text where it should have different text when other partial view is loaded. How can I change section contents on change of partial view ?

I tried to move section to partial views but in that case it is not loaded at all. Can't we define section in partial view which is declared in layout view ?

Please suggest

Comment: can you please tell me both partial view you have in same view  or in different view ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define sections in partial views. They must be defined in the main view. So basically what you need is to update 2 different portions of your DOM when a link is clicked. One possible way to achieve this is to [render the partial view to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4344602/29407) inside the controller action and then return a JSON result containing the 2 properties with the corresponding partial contents.

```
return Json(new
{
    partialHtml = RenderPartialViewToString("_SomePartial"),
    sectionHtml = RenderPartialViewToString("_SomeSection")
});
```

and then:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result) {
        // first update the partial
        $('#partialContainerId').html(partialHtml);

        // now update the section
        $('.rt-article-title').html(sectionHtml);
    }
});
```

You could externalize the contents of the section inside a partial.

Comment: thanks for the response. what will be URL in this case and this code need to be added in main view and controller action or partial view/controller action?

Comment: The url will be the url of the controller action that you are invoking with an AJAX call. Since the code I have shown is javascript it must go into a separate javascript file.