# Send PartialView content as email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sendmail, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a PartialView that contains a HTML code with Razor annotations. It generates to me a page that I want to send by email to anyone. Is there a way to translate this PartialView into HTML content to send it?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://akinyusufer.blogspot.in/2011/05/razor-render-mvc3-view-render-to-string.html

Comment: Possibly same concern/answer as this:
 
[ASP.NET MVC Razor: How to render a Razor Partial View's HTML inside the controller action](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4344602/1036187)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Razor: How to render a Razor Partial View's HTML inside the controller action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344533/asp-net-mvc-razor-how-to-render-a-razor-partial-views-html-inside-the-controll)

Comment: Solved with that post! Thank you all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using **MvcMailer** which does exactly what you want (without you having to write the code for it.. it can also do it asynchronously):

https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide

**Update**

As stated at the comments, the solution for implementing it yourself (I still think MvcMailer will make your life easier):

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    ViewData.Model = model;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

( [ASP.NET MVC Razor: How to render a Razor Partial View's HTML inside the controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344533/asp-net-mvc-razor-how-to-render-a-razor-partial-views-html-inside-the-controll/4344602#4344602) )