# How to render a controller's action result to string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

according to the [ASP.NET MVC Razor: How to render a Razor Partial View's HTML inside the controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344533/asp-net-mvc-razor-how-to-render-a-razor-partial-views-html-inside-the-controll) I'm can render a View to a string. But, is it possible to invoke an action inside the controller and render the result to a string ?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do? Consider using child actions.

Comment: I'm trying to put that action result inside the Json response and update a DOM element on the client side. I don't want to use jquery in this scenario

Comment: Its hard understand what you try to do;) Is it ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

What I tend to do for things like this is return a PartialView which will have any of the HTML I need for the JavaScript to use. Keep in mind that in HTTP, everything is text already, so you don't need to do something special to render the result to a string to return to an AJAX call.

I'll have a PartialView which has the HTML I need, pass it back to the Ajax call using something like `return PartialView("ViewName", model)`, then do whatever I need to on the client side - such as appending that HTML to a node in the DOM.